# How to update ProgressBar which is a child view of GalleryView android

Tags: android, progress-bar, baseadapter, galleryview

Is there any way to update the progress bar which is child view (row) of GalleryView with baseAdaptper.

I have tried some with this code

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) ((View) mGalleryView.getChildAt(position))
                            .findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mProgressBar.setProgress(value);
```

It is working fine but progress bar not filling completely.

For more clarity please check the attached images.
When I am trying to update the progressbar with in the gallery it looks some what like this.

[image]
[image]

Expecting to be.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is way to update. That answers your question.

Comment: @Shrikant could you please check my question now.

Comment: @AndroSelva Thanks for your interest could you please check the question now, I have updated the question with what i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Posting Answer to my own Question. I would like to thank *Andro Selva* who showed his interest to solve this question.

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) ((View) mGalleryView.getChildAt(position))
                            .findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mProgressBar.setMax(100);
mProgressBar.setProgress(value);
```

After the above lines of code.

```
mGalleryView.invalidate();
```

adding above line resolved my issue to get expecting output.

Regards
Vinay Kumar